# ATmega328P development board not working

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, pcb-design, arduino-uno

I've made a development board for ATmega328P like Arduino Uno.

[image: SCHEMATIC]

*Fig. 1 - schematic*

---

[image: bottom layer]

*Fig. 2 - bottom layer*

---

[image: top layer]

*Fig. 3 - top layer*

---

I am able to upload the code using FTDI chip (I've used the chip which has boot loader in it). However the code is not working; I mean the LED connected to pin 14 is not blinking.

When I check the supply voltage at pin 7 I get 4.9 V, but when I check the same at GPIO it is giving 0.3 V.

I'm new to PCB designing. Please let me know what could have gone wrong.

```
void setup() {
   pinMode(14, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
    delay(1000);              // wait for a second
    digitalWrite(14, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
    delay(1000);              // wait for a second
}
```

[image: FINAL BOARD]

Comment: Have you set the configuration bits? I guess the controller is not running.

Comment: hello Mike yes, also even if i use the flased controller from uno . it will not work.

Comment: @Sanmvegsaini what is R5 then? ... looks like a pullup on the reset line to me

Comment: yes it is 10k Pull up

Comment: your code is wrong `pinMode(8, OUTPUT)` sets physical pin 14 of ATMEGA328 as output on Arduino UNO

Comment: ok let me try it out. is there any document for this please provide the link.

Comment: HI jsotola yessssssss the code is wrong.thank you very muchh. and please if you have any doc regarding this sendit to anilsuha831@gmail.com. thanks once again...

Comment: google `arduino uno schematic`

Answer (score 2):

The code is wrong because you are using the pin physical of the microcontroller like an Arduino pin. You need to review ATmega168/328P-Arduino Pin Mapping able on the [Arduino web page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping168)

[image: ATmega168/328P-Arduino Pin Mapping]

I recommend you to review the source code where these pins are defined [pins_arduino.h - Pin definition functions for Arduino](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/variants/standard/pins_arduino.h)